# CSS named rgba colors

Tags: css

I would like to define colors with opacity
I know that it is possible to do this via rgba colors, but I like the ease of named colors. e.g.:

```css
background-color: red;
```

Is there a way to combine the two?

Comment: I personally use the Chrome developer tools to get colours value in either HEX, RGB or RGBA (with opacity). There is a color picker + toggle to choose the type of colour you want to use in your CSS.

Comment: Are you aware that you can easily do this with a preprocessor such as LESS or SASS?

Comment: Yes, SASS can do this directly exactly as required...as stated in my answer.

Comment: you could use opacity: 0.5; property for any element and class

Comment: While the `rgba()` function is annoying, hexadecimal colors with alpha are coming. Until then, I think you can see from the complexity of pure CSS solutions that you'll be best off just going with `rgba()` or using a preprocessor.

Comment: Unless you want to use LESS or SASS, why don't you just look up the color codes [here](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use "red" in `rgba(red,0.5)` with standard CSS, but you can do

```css
background: red;
opacity: 0.5;
```

The down side is that opacity will affect child elements, which `rgba(255,0,0,0.5)` will not.

By using pseudo element you can create a similar effect.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
}
div:first-child {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
div ~ div:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  right: 0; bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
<div>Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way would be to apply the color and the opacity separately like this:

```
someElement {
   background: blue; 
   opacity: .5;
}
```

But, this won't be possible to do selectively since opacity applies to the entire element, not any one aspect of the element. Here, you'll see that the background color and the font color are both affected.

```css
div { background: yellow; 
      color:green;
      opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div>This is my div</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No...this is not possible in raw CSS.

CSS preprocessors however can do this

**SASS**

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(red,0.5);
}
```

compiles to

**CSS**

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

[**SASSMeister Demo**](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/634e02587238d9c579afb4d659d20e5f)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you can't. There are no named alpha channel colors in the css3 specification.

You can read more about it in
https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color-3/#colorunits

If what you want is to have a nemonic to apply to backgrounds, may be the best is to create a class for that:

```
.red-50 {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.red-75 {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

And apply to your html elements

```
<div class="red-50 someOtherClass"></div>
```

Comment: The downside of this is that styling has now moved from the CSS to the HTML, which is generally undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS3 `rgba()` and `hsla()` functions are the only way to directly specify a color with alpha. However, if use of [less](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) is allowed, colors can be assigned to variables and used similarly to the builtin named colors. A less example:

```
@red50: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);

.something {
    background-color: @red50;
}
```